# How to link different databases?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design, etl, network

We are a company doing surveys with different kind of questionnaires. There is a company in Mumbai (MySQL) specialized in Type 1 questionnaire and one in Peru (SQL-Server) specialized in Type 2. I also work with a CRM system as Salesforce and want to connect these data as well.

I thought about getting all these data into one in-house database using ETL. I was curious if it is possible to virtually connect these data warehouses so I do not need a DW in-house and can query the data where they are stored but can connect to them. Is this possible? I could not find anything but maybe I am looking with the wrong vocabulary.

Comment: How will you connect the survey data with salesforce? Do you you need to push data into salesforce or will you just read data from sf and combine?

Comment: How much data is involved? How many surveys? How many Mb/Gb?

Comment: 1. I will read data from sf and combine. 2. All together we have about 500 GB of data and a few thousand surveys.

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I'd use SSIS and import everything into a DW locally. Then you can do whatever you want/need with minimal impact to all of those remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult question to answer. The right solution for **you** will depend upon several factors such as cost and availablity of resources and expertise. But the solution should be driven by **the  requirements.**

Before you try to select a technical solution it is worth considering what the end result should look like.

Where is the data going and for what purpose? Do you want reporting and analytics?

Who is going to use this data and how? (Executives? Analysts? Marketing? Sales? Customer Service?) What level detail does each group need? (Raw ? Aggregated?) How often? When? How fast?

Does it need to be integrated with Salesforce?

If you decide the solution is a data warehouse I would seriously consider a cloud based alternative. As you already have cloud based software and you are spread across different countries.